# Syntax error near INTERSECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, intersect

```
select SOURCE_SYS_CD,COUNT(*) as [COUNT BY APP] from STAGING_TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY SOURCE_SYS_CD
ORDER BY SOURCE_SYS_CD
INTERSECT 
select SOURCE_SYS_CD,COUNT(*) as [COUNT BY APP] from TMS..TB_TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY SOURCE_SYS_CD
ORDER BY SOURCE_SYS_CD
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in above query? They execute independently but throw error on using intersect. How to find common rows between two tables?

Comment: Probably you need to remove all but the last `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Malk - Thanks Malk, please add the answer. You deserve the points! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER BY` is your culprit.

It is not valid on subqueries/derived tables (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=sql.105).aspx). Meaning there should only be 1 ORDER BY clause at the end of the query.

Remove all but the last ORDER BY and you should be good.

```
select SOURCE_SYS_CD,COUNT(*) as [COUNT BY APP] from STAGING_TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY SOURCE_SYS_CD
INTERSECT 
select SOURCE_SYS_CD,COUNT(*) as [COUNT BY APP] from TMS..TB_TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY SOURCE_SYS_CD
ORDER BY SOURCE_SYS_CD
```